# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module when import custom lib in google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am create a javascript lib and tried to import into my project, I tried to added dependencies into the google chrome extension code like this in the `package.json`:

```
"js-wheel": "git+https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/js-wheel.git",
```

and import modual in the google chrome extension project like this:

```
import { Auth,Validate } from "js-wheel";
```

when I run this code, the console shows error like this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

this is the js-wheel `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "js-wheel",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/js-wheel.git"
  },
  "author": "jiangtingqiang@gmail.com",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/js-wheel/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/js-wheel#readme"
}
```

I have already tried to define the `js-wheel` to module, why still shows this error? where am I doing wrong? what should I do to fix this problem? In the public lib, I define the index.js like this:

```
import BaseMethods from "./src/utils/data/checker";
import Validate from "./src/utils/data/validate";
import Auth from "./src/auth/extension/auth";

export default {
    BaseMethods,
    Validate,
    Auth
}
```

and define the export function like this way:

```
const Validate = {
    
    mobileCheck: (mobile) => {
        let reg = /^[1][3,4,5,7,8][0-9]{9}$/
        return reg.test(mobile)
    }
}

export default Validate
```

I searched from intenet and tell me to tweak the `package.json` type to `module`, but still not fix this problem. I found the error was throw in the js-wheel internal from this line:

```
import BaseMethods from "./src/utils/data/checker";
```

why could not using this way to import in the `js-wheel` ?

Comment: And none of [these questions](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=chrome+extension+%22cannot+use+import+statement+outside+a+module%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com) has an answer?

Comment: Please show how you are integrating your JS into the HTML.

Comment: I integrating the js-wheel using npm install from git url. @connexo

Comment: I don't know about extension development at all, but usually `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` means you failed to specify `type="module"` in your `script`  tag.

Comment: I did not use the js-wheel by using the <script> , I using it in the Vue using import command, but did not know how to specify the js-wheel as a module in the import way. @connexo